# c - strtok() crashing

Tags: c, strtok

I got this problem with strtok:

```
void getFile(FILE *fp, TParts *str)
{
    char a[60], *b;
    int p = 0, m = 0;
    while(fgets(a, 60, fp) != NULL)
    {
        b = strtok(a, '$');
...
```

The program crashes when strtok is called. Tokens in strings are separated with $. What's wrong?

Comment: That second argument to `strtok` is supposed to be a string, like `"$"`, not a character like `'$'`.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings — the answer was in front of you!

Comment: Aside: if you make the delimiter string to be `"$\n"` you will also filter out any final newline retained by `fgets`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I don't think enabling compiler warnings is the problem.  Any compiler should warn about passing an `int` argument to a function expecting a `char*`. I'd be surprised if it were possible to turn that warning off. Either the OP just ignored the warning, or the actual code is missing the required `#include <string.h>` and the compiler didn't complain about the (C90-only) implicit declaration of `strtok` -- or it did and the OP ignored that as well.

Comment: Did you have the required `#include <string.h>` at the top of your source file?

Comment: @KeithThompson mybad: "please look at and fix compiler warnings." What a terrible mistake to cause you to type several lines of comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is dued to second argument of `strtok` must be a string. Here is a working example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[60] = "fadf$safgs$afd$", *b;

    b = strtok(a, "$");

    while( b != NULL ) {
          printf( " %s\n", b );

          b = strtok(NULL, "$");
    }

    return 0;
}
```